# Add months to plot of forecast

Tags: r, ggplot2, forecasting

I generated a one-year forecast using monthly data from January 2017 to July 2019 with an innovations state space model for exponential smoothing.

```r
library("forecast") 
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")

myData<-c(11878838,11025085,13346905,11657777,12670973,12321707,10668589,13296366,10976129,13383487,11157827,9064816,
          10712529,11058177,11220417,12010494,11824792,10623115,10171066,13388616,11249052,14134987,10795036,9001540,
          10561734,10658972,11689656,10351909,11062358,9858083,9779142)

ts_myData<-ts(myData, frequency=12, start=c(2017,1), end=c(2019,7))

model<-ets(ts_myData, model="MNM")

fcast_units<-forecast(model, h=12, PI=TRUE)  

autoplot(fcast_units)+
  xlab("Year")+
  ylab("Number of units")+
  ggtitle("My forecast")+
  scale_y_continuous(label=comma) # this line is to avoid scientific notation and use the format you see on the y-label
```

The problem is that I want to change the x-axis of the plot, but can't seem to figure out how. I want to see all the months, since January 2017 up to July 2020. Right now the plot looks like this.

[image: plot of past observations and forecast]

If you look at the current plot, you can deduce that the white vertical lines represent the beginning and the end of the year and the month of June, but I want to have all 12 per year. I tried using `scale_x_date` and `scale_x_datetime` but they didn't work (maybe I didn't especify the parameters correctly?). Maybe the issue is that `fcast` is of class `forecast`? I'm not sure.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check [geom_vline](www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-add-straight-lines-to-a-plot-horizontal-vertical-and-regression-lines) as it might do the trick for your case.

Answer (score 0):

This code kind of works.

```
autoplot(fcast_units)+
  xlab("Year")+
  ylab("Number of units")+
  ggtitle("My forecast")+
  scale_y_continuous(label=comma)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2017 , 2020, 1/6))
```